# Swift 3 Exclude Item in For Loop

Tags: swift

Can I directly exclude a certain value or object in the declaration of the for loop in Swift? I'm trying to do something like this, where I loop over indices, but I'd like to filter out `someIndex` in the same line.

```
func updateTabsEnabled(isShowing: Bool) {
    for index in 0..<viewControllers!.count, index != someIndex {
        tabBar.items![index].isEnabled = !isShowing
    }
}
```

I thought this was possible in Swift 3, although I can't remember and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) didn't seem to have it in there, although I may have missed it.

Comment: You should never use `0..<array.count` use `array.indices` instead.

Comment: @Alexander The [half open range] (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) example here from Apple's docs uses array.count?

Comment: Apple's introductory Swift material isn't the arbiter of code style. There are **countless** questions I've seen come up on this site, relating to people accidentally typing `0...array.count`. There's no reason not to use `array.indices`.

Comment: @Alexander I never said it was the arbiter of code style. I am interested in learning more about array.indices, however, simple google searches don't reveal much. Could you link me some more info please?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say much: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2854166-indices It's semantically equivalent to `0..<array.count`, without the opportunity of introducing an off-by-one error by accidentally typing `...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `where` keyword and then add the condition

```
func updateTabsEnabled(isShowing: Bool) {
    for index in 0..<viewControllers!.count where index != someIndex {
        tabBar.items![index].isEnabled = !isShowing
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, great! I was doing `,where` instead of `where` - thanks.